# How to fix a looping and a break bug within a Rock, Paper, Scissors program?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, break

I wrote a basic program to run rock, paper, scissors in Powershell.

```
import random

print("Lets play Rock, Paper, Scissors...")
print("Type 'quit' to quit the game")
pwins = 0
cwins = 0
winning_score = 2

while pwins < winning_score and cwins < winning_score:
    print(f"Player wins:{pwins} | Computer wins: {cwins}")
    p1 = input("Player's move: ").lower()
    
    rand_num = random.randint(0,2)
    if rand_num == 0:
        computer = "rock"
    elif rand_num == 1:
        computer = "paper"
    else:
        computer = "scissors"

    if p1 == "quit" or p1 == "q":
        break
        
    print(f"Computer chooses: {computer}")

    if p1 == computer:
        print("It's a tie...")
        p1 = input("Player's move: ").lower()

    if p1 == "rock":
        if computer == "paper":
            print("Computer wins")
            cwins += 1
        else:
            print("Player wins")
            pwins += 1
    elif p1 == "paper":
        if computer == "scissors":
            print("Computer wins")
            cwins += 1
        else:
            print("Player wins")
            pwins += 1
    elif p1 == "scissors":
        if computer == "rock":
            print("Computer wins")
            cwins += 1
        else:
            print("Player wins")
            pwins += 1
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid move!")

    print(f"Final score... Player: {pwins} | Computer: {cwins}")

    if pwins > cwins:
        print("Congrats, you won!")
    elif pwins < cwins:
        replay = input("You lost...Do you want to play again? (y/n) ")
    if replay == "y":
        cwins = 0
        pwins = 0
    else:
        print("Loser!")
    else:
        print("It's a tie")`
```

The issue lies in whenever I get a p1 == computer tie, if I choose to quit immediately after, I get a bug. I get "Please enter a valid move!" as a response. If I type "quit" a second time after, the program will properly end.

The second issue is once the player loses and the program asks "Do you want to play again? (y/n)". If I choose "y" the program does not loop and will simply end.

I have tried moving the sections of code and placing them in different orders to get the break and loop to function properly, but I am at a loss because the issue would not be fixed and other bugs would occur. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The issue is that after you enter your 'q', you don't have any conditions catching the ```q```.  So I'm guessing an ```elif p1 == "q":  break``` might be the way to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the bugs you're encountering. This can probably fix them.

Whenever you get a p1 == computer tie, if you choose to quit immediately it will return enter a valid move. This is expected because in your code, after a tie, the program will ask for another input without being able to validate the input if its a break. To fix this, you should add this every time you asked for an input from the user.

```
if p1 == "quit" or p1 == "q":
    break
```

For your 2nd bug. Try recreating the last part of your code to this instead.

1. Display final score
2. Say if the player losses, wins, or it a tie.
3. Then ask if the player want to play again.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Your tip helped fix the first bug but the solution to the second bug still eludes me.

    print(f"Final score... Player: {pwins} | Computer: {cwins}")

    if pwins > cwins:
     print("Congrats, you won!")
    elif pwins < cwins:
     print("You lost...")
    else:
     print("It's a tie")

    replay = input("Do you want to play again? (y/n) ")
    if replay == "y":
     pwins = 0
     cwins = 0
    else:
     print("Loser!")

After getting to the "Do you want to play again? (y/n)", inputting "y" does not reset the loop. The program still exits